# Debian installation USB boots to GRUBv2 rather than GUI

Tags: debian, debian-installer, debian-cd

I have downloaded the Debian 8 AMD x64 iso and have attempted to make a bootable USB using Rufus on my PC and I have also tried this using UNetbootin on Ubuntu.

I was expecting a graphical user interface to install the OS as I had on my virtual machine but instead I get a command line interface labelled GRUBv2.

The laptop BIOS will boot to USB and has done before for the Ubuntu install so unsure how to get Debian to install via GUI.

How to fix?

Comment: GRUB is the bootloader, so if that's all you see then the OS is not booting. Does GRUB give you any options to choose from? If all you get is a command prompt, then you're missing the GRUB configuration file.

Comment: If i hit tab I get a list of commands like boot, ls, etc

Comment: Yeah, you're in the GRUB bootloader. It couldn't find a config file where it expected it, hence it dropped you at the shell. Debian advises against using UNetbootin. Instead, simply write the ISO to the USB drive's block device. See https://www.debian.org/CD/faq/#write-usb

Comment: I have tried the cp <file> <device> option, this time it shows the GRUB menu with the option to boot into Ubuntu (my current OS) but no Debian option.

Comment: Unfortunately, there's not much more I can advise without the hardware in my hands. A number of things could be wrong, and it would take trial and error to figure it out. Since you have Ubuntu already installed, you can use Debootstrap to install a base Debian system from within Ubuntu. However, that's an advanced installation method; no GUI. Also keep in mind that when dual-booting Linux OSs you'll want only one of them to be in charge of maintaining the GRUB configuration. https://manpages.debian.org/jessie/debootstrap/debootstrap.8.en.html

Comment: Another option is to install Debian in the virtual machine, and then copy it to the laptop. I've migrated Gentoo Linux from one PC to another using that method; no reinstallation. You'd have to configure Ubuntu's GRUB yourself to also boot Debian, but generally, it works.

Comment: Debian images have not (yet) been signed for Secure Boot.  You will need to disable Secure Boot in your BIOS first, if your PC was designed to run a Windows OS released in the last 5 years or so.  https://www.debian.org/releases/stable/amd64/ch03s06.html.en#UEFI

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed by using Rufus in Windows to create the boot USB stick and ensuring DD Image Mode was used instead of the default ISO Image Mode. There is an alert that mentions this when attempting to create a Debian USB in ISO image mode.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure, that the GRUB is loaded from your stick? Have you enabled booting from USB device on your PC? For writing Linux ISO to external device use `dd` command.